# MySQL - is there a way to save searches to speed up future redundant queries?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement a feature where a user can request to save a search. If requested, the rows found in the search will be tagged so in the future, if the same search is performed, the program only has to look for that tag.

Would this speed up future redundant queries? Is there a feature in MySQL that does this? I'm trying to avoid creating a new table for every saved search.

Thanks,

fertileneutrino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with 'tag, id', i.e. a list of all the ids found, and associate them with a tag.

This will work fine, but, if new stuff is added the search won't be updated. You said to save the rows not the search.

If you want to save the search then create a view.

Comment: A view is a database feature; it's not what you want. As the answer said you need to setup a new table where you store the results from the previous search.

Comment: it seems that views do not speed up future queries. it still takes the same time to return all information in a view than to just perform the same search again on the data. is this true?

Comment: @fertileneutrino Mostly. Some of it gets optimized a bit, but yah, mostly it takes the same amount of time. MySQL does not support materialized views which are faster. They can be updated, or you can retrieve the cached information. In any case you don't want to create a view for each search, that would be nuts - only create a few views for "pre-packaged" searches.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does have a query cache that can be [configured](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-configuration.html) either to be always on, always off, or only "on-demand", when used with `SELECT SQL_CACHE`.

Note that the MySQL query cache will always be invalidated if the data in the tables changes, so if your data is frequently updated, these results won't remain cached long.  However, if your data is not frequently updated, it'll be very effective.

If you wanted your users' "stored searches" to remain cached even if the data they searched in is updated, and are more concerned about saving database load than you are about the result being fresh, then you will need to implement some sort of cache in your application - on the "client" side of the MySQL client-server connection.